# How to create a child page that has the same content type as parent page?

Tags: nodes

I enabled the Book module on drupal 7 and created 2 new content types. Let said I created a new "content type A" and "content type B", and keep the book module content type as "Book page". The issue I have is that whenever I adding a child page on a "Content type A" or the "Content type B" page, these child pages are "Book page" content type. **How to keep these child page the same content type as parent page?**

**PS: I see there is a "Books" setting under "content > books" tab. But it only allow me to select one content type as child page.**

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It would allow infinite trees of content, and Books module isn't quite ready for that. It's been a long time since I was using it, so I'm not going to add it as an answer.

Comment: @Mołot If this is not possible at the moment. How about the Breadcrumb? right now, the child page is not under the parent page because they are not the same content type. Should I ask this as a new question or just add to my question?

Comment: @Mołot Oh no, eveything is not right, even the "Print" PDF not grouping them together

Comment: Honestly, I think I'm lost now, wasn't quite able to follow your train of thoughts. Sorry. For new question / edit existing one - as long as there are no answers, you are free to do as you see fit. Oh, and please remember that last time I actually used Book was in 6, before 7 got stable, so I may be wrong about it. Don't assume I'm right, I posted what I think to help you with your thinking and tinkering, but that's not any kind of "for sure truth".

Comment: I don't get it. You can't create a content type B node and set a parent for it? Or are you wondering, that when you hit create book page, that it is a book page? Cause that's the way it should go. You first choose a content type to create `/node/add/content_type` and then set a parent (if you implemented such a feature).

Comment: @koivo a child page is still able to under a parent page but the breadcrumb can not

Comment: Ah, then you have to customize your breadcrumbs. Maybe https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs or https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs fit your needs.

Comment: @Mołot I'm thinking using one type of "content type" and adding taxonomy field for "content type option". That may work lol

Answer (score 1):

I found a module that does the job, which is [Book made simple](https://www.drupal.org/project/book_made_simple). This module add the setting on content type and have the option for "**SELECT CONTENT-TYPES ALLOWED AS CHILD**.", "**SELECT CONTENT-TYPES ALLOWED AS PARENT**" and "**Other Settings**". Then a dropdown listbox will be added in the books link like the one on screenshot. I hope Drupal 8 has a similar feature like this.

PS: One of the issue is "[Printer](https://www.drupal.org/project/print)" module also print "Add child page" on each page.

[image]