# Is it possible to set a field permission Per Option?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

On Drupal 7. Let say I have a "field A" on a "Content Type A". with the following option and and permission. Is there a way to set a field permission based on an option?

**Field A (Term reference: select list)**

- Option 1 Term A (all authenticated users are able to see and select this option)
- Option 2 Term B (Only Editor and Administrator users can see and select this option)
- Option 3 Term C (Only Administrator can see and select this option)

Comment: AFAIK there's no module that do that. In addition I see some problems. What happens if Editor selects option 2, and a normal user sees the node? What will be displayed in that field? May be if you explain your problem we can suggest an appropiate solution without coding

Comment: @tunic I was trying to create a site that allow user to create book based on their role for different type of book. But the book module does not allow user to create a child page that has the same content type as parent page(see this page for details http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125203). So, my idea is to use one "content type" with term reference field.